# Siliconed round windows before repainting jambs - should have done it after?

Tags: painting, plaster, repainting, silicone

I'm repainting a room.  I've scraped back  the loose paint (*in places back to plaster*), filled, sugar soaped and, to my low standards, it's ready to paint.

I also scraped out the old mouldy silicone round the windows and replaced it with fresh silicone.  I immediately regretted that - at the thin edges where I smoothed it there is enough silicone to prevent paint adhesion, but not enough to hide the colour of the plaster (*e.g. at the arrow*).

Clearly the silicone should have gone on after painting.

Now it's done, how best to remedy so as not to leave an ugly line around the window when I repaint it?

- am I worrying about nothing?
- is there a primer or other product that will allow me to paint over this with water-based emulsion?
- can I remove the new silicone from the plaster/old paint sufficiently well for it to be over-painted?  How?

[image]

Comment: Some caulk, even silicone, is paintable. What does _your_ tube say? The paint probably won't last as long on the caulk as it will on the wall, so you'll probably need to repaint more often than you'd prefer, but you'll have fresher looking paint!

Comment: the silicone says "not paintable"

Comment: @FreeMan You can use a shellac primer on non-paintable silicone

Comment: @MonkeyZeus cool! I had no idea...

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with spending some more money to avoid labor then you can buy a [shellac primer](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Zinsser-1-qt-B-I-N-Shellac-Based-White-Interior-Primer-and-Sealer-00904/100398380) to paint over the silicone and then apply regular paint. Before painting clean the silicone with denatured alcohol for best adhesion. It is said that oil-based paints will stick to silicone as well.

If not then scrape off the new silicone and apply [paintable silicone](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-Silicone-2-Paintable-Silicone-10-1-oz-White-Paintable-Caulk-GE7000/100012232) or the cheaper [painter's caulk](https://www.homedepot.com/p/DAP-Alex-10-1-oz-White-Painter-s-All-Purpose-Acrylic-Latex-Caulk-18609/100078928).